# Optimize INNER JOIN statements through column indexes

Tags: sql-server, join, query-optimization, sql-server-2014-express

I'm trying to optimize my INNER JOIN statements on the following tables:

[articlegroups] contains ~700 rows
[products] contains ~150.000 rows
[products_category_mapping] contains 1 up to 3 rows for each product in [products] (so anywhere between 150.000 and 450.000 rows)

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT ga.label_sp,ga.label_en,ga.slug_sp,ga.slug_en,ga.pagetitle_sp,ga.pagetitle_en,ga.image_sp,ga.image_en,ga.description_sp,ga.description_en,ga.metadescription_sp,ga.metadescription_en
FROM articlegroups ga WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN products_category_mapping pcm on pcm.articlegroup_id=ga.id
INNER JOIN products gp on gp.id=pcm.artikelid
WHERE gp.id=<PRODUCTID> AND ga.catlevel=0
```

I read here http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/tuning-joins/ that a thing I can do is to add indexes to the columns on which the tables are joined.

Now I wonder what would result in the best performance: 
Adding an index to products_category_mapping.artikelid and/or to products_category_mapping.articlegroup_id and what kind of index? Should I add indexes to both columns? Should I make one of them clustered and if so which one?
I have now added indexes to both columns and a clustered index on products_category_mapping.artikelid since I though that last column could have the most different results and would require the most speed. I'm not sure if I'm correct in what I'm doing now though.

Comment: From what table do your fields `label` and `page` come? If you can add them as `include` to your index, you may be able to avoid hitting the table altogether.

Comment: @BrianStork see my updated statement. I also added all the fields in my query (which I removed for simplicity). Does your suggestion still work with more fields and if so, how would I include these in my index to avoid hitting that table?

Answer (score 0):

`ARTICLEGROUPS` has just 700 rows.This is a small table and you can try not indexing this as well. The columns used here are `GA.ID, GA.CATLEVEL`. May be you can try the below index.

```
Create Index IX_id on ARTICLEGROUPS (id) Include (CATLEVEL asc);
```

`PRODUCTS` has 150000 rows, and column used is `GP.ID.` If `LABEL` and `PAGE` are not from `PRODUCTS`, try

```
Create Clustered Index IX_id on PRODUCTS (id);
```

else create

```
Create Index IX_id on PRODUCTS (id) Include (..); -- Pls fill include part.
```

`PRODUCTS_CATEGORY_MAPPING` has 150000 < rows. Columns used `PCM.ARTICLEGROUP_ID` and `PCM.ARTIKELID`. try the below and see.

```
Create Index IX_agid on PRODUCTS_CATEGORY_MAPPING (ARTICLEGROUP_ID) Include (..) --If LABEL or PAGE is from this table add thosem coumns in the include part)

Create Index IX_aid on PRODUCTS_CATEGORY_MAPPING (ARTIKELID) Include (..) --If LABEL or PAGE is from this table add those columns in the include part)
```

See the execution plan for the query after adding index. I am adding this in the answer part, as i found it very clumsy when I wrote this in comment part, hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks! See my updated statement. I added all the fields in my query (which I removed for simplicity). Does your suggestion still work with more fields in the query? Not sure which of your suggestions I should then use...

Comment: The `include` fields in an index become part of the index but not indexed. Think of an index like another table, ordered the way you specify. This is how it is easy to find a row you want (because it's sorted properly). The `include` columns are part of the index, but they aren't sorted. So when you quickly find the row you want, the `include` data is available in the index, and you don't have to go back to the table to get it. If you write the index with the indexed columns needed to identify the records, then `include` the data you want to see, you should be good.

Comment: @BrianStork Ok, thank you. But now that you see my table structure, which indexes are still relevant? [PRODUCTS_CATEGORY_MAPPING ] contains 150K-450K rows. `LABEL or PAGE` are both part of [articlegroups] and not of [PRODUCTS_CATEGORY_MAPPING], so the last 2 indexes in Jithin's answer would not be correct right? I'm still confused which indexes to create and what fields to use in the include statement. Can you help?